# sqlite3 fts5 contentless or content=external table, how store and read a non-FTS column value

Tags: database, sqlite, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I am working with an **SQLite3** database. And I want to create an **FTS5** content-less (content="") or content="external table" table to save space and prevent duplication of data (which occurs if I don't use a content-less or external-content table).

My scenario =>

```
tableA (textColumn, idColumn)
tableB (textColumn, idColumn)
tableFTS5 (textColumn, textIdColumn, tableNameColumn)
```

What I do =>

I insert data into tableA and tableB.
Then I read all rows from tableA and insert into tableFTS5 table as

```
tableFTS5.textColumn = tableA.textColumn, 
tableFTS5.textIdColumn = tableA.idColumn,
tableFTS5.tableNameColumn = "tableA"
```

I repeat this for tableB also with tableFTS5.tableNameColumn = "tableB".

What I need is =>

I want to query tableFTS5 for some text and I want to retrieve just tableFTS5.textIdColumn and tableFTS5.tableNameColumn.
With these two column values in hand, I can retrieve the original data from tableA or tableB.

Is it possible to retrieve these columns from tableFTS5 if tableFTS5 is a content-less or content="external" table, maybe with some triggers or any other method ?

My source of info about this [Link to SQLite3 FTS5 docs](https://www.sqlite.org/fts5.html#external_content_and_contentless_tables)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So one approach I can take is =>

I have two main tables with text data (I don't want to duplicate this data).

And I create one mapping table to map the main table names and their text ids to rowids of FTS table.

And I have one FTS content-less table which only returns rowids.

But with this approach I have to manage insert, delete operations for FTS table and mapping table too. This got too complicated to manage so I decided to go for creating individual FTS table for every main table and setting content="that main table name"

But I would really prefer if there is an option for content-less FTS table to store and return some user specified columns for the purpose of storing some ids and not the text content columns (because that would create duplication of text).

What I was trying to achieve is called one to one polymorphic relationship so I don't have to create too many tables.

If I had this option for content-less FTS table then for 6 text data tables I would create only one FTS table, so total tables = 7.
But now without this option I would create 12 tables, 6 main and 6 FTS

I request developers to add this option to sqlite. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a contentless fts5 table:

```sql
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fts_tbl USING fts5(a, b, c, content='')
```

Create triggers so it updates as your table you want indexed updates:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tbl_ai AFTER INSERT ON tbl BEGIN
  INSERT INTO fts_tbl(rowid, a, b, c) VALUES (new.ROWID, new.a, new.b, new.c);
END
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tbl_ad AFTER DELETE ON tbl BEGIN
  INSERT INTO fts_tbl(fts_tbl, rowid, a, b ,c) VALUES('delete', old.ROWID, old.a, old.b, old.c);
END
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS tbl_au AFTER UPDATE ON tbl BEGIN
  INSERT INTO fts_tbl(fts_tbl, rowid, a, b, c) VALUES('delete', old.ROWID, old.a, old.b, old.c);
  INSERT INTO fts_tbl(rowid, a, b, c) VALUES (new.ROWID, new.a, new.b, new.c);
END
```

Then fill it with data from your table of interest:

```sql
INSERT INTO fts5_tbl (rowid, a, b, c) SELECT ROWID, a, b, c FROM tbl
```

Now you can query it and return data from your table like this:

```sql
SELECT rank, t.a, t.b, t.c FROM tbl t JOIN fts_tbl f ON t.ROWID = f.ROWID WHERE fts_tbl MATCH "search" ORDER BY rank;
```

Comment: I didn't know you could perform join with FTS virtual table. Thanks for this info. But with this method, primary id of 1st table is bound with rowid of FTS table. Now I can't add primary id of 2nd table because that will lead to duplicate rowids in FTS table. What I want, is to store the primary ids of both data tables in seperate columns in FTS table. I am trying to achieve polymorphic relation between two data tables and one FTS table without creating duplicate data

Comment: I guess what I am trying to achieve is not possible in sqlite yet. This is even not possible in FTS feature of Mysql. In Mysql this is only possible with duplication of data. I was just expecting too much from sqlite. Its still excellent technology. I love content-less table feature of FTS in sqlite. Finally what I did was I created seperate FTS table for each data table. This is the popular approach. But I think if polymorphism was possible with contentless FTS table then total FTS index size on disk would reduce by half

Comment: More info here-  
SQLite Forum: sqlite3 fts5 contentless or content=external table, how store and read a non-FTS column value
https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/fa35fca3d9